# Class primary does not exist

Tags: php, class, yii2

Im getting this error "Class primary does not exist" often when trying to do something with Model Objects.

For example:

```
$new_product = new Product();
$new_product->setAttribute('mfr', $product->getAttribute('mfr'));
$new_product->save();
```

Class Product is declared as:

```
class Product extends ActiveRecord
```

When i put 'false' into save function parameter, like this:

```
$new_product->save(false);
```

then it saved. But as I've Googled so far, then 'false' in save parameter will turn off Model data validating which is not good obviously.

So the question is why this error "Class primary does not exist" appear while doing something with Model objects. What I'm missing here which cause this error and what are my options to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a Class reference error in your rules for Product. It sounds like it might be a related table.

Comment: Yeah I had some old code I tried to use. Pretty much there was a mistake in rules function, had wrong property type. Tried to tell Model that id was primary type :D Ty for the help.